# Split Figma json into chunks

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a 6000 lines of nested dictionary and I want to split into chunks of 200 lines.
I want to then send each chunk to GPT model with a prompt.

Is there a way to split the chunks logically such that each chunk is a valid json ?

Sample json

```
{
"name": "WMS Web UI",
"lastModified": "2023-07-31T10: 17: 26Z",
"thumbnailUrl": "https: //s3-alpha.figma.com/thumbnails/3ca7f866-5d92-4cc8-a5dc-46087888cd06?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQ4GOSFWC7ZQJHYXS%2F20230803%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230803T000000Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ced8db9ae970ad0c60e8ee79b0f90b458f5e9dd130fe808eb5e7e2c640d968ed",
"version": "3909344649",
"role": "viewer",
"editorType": "figma",
"linkAccess": "org_view",
"nodes": {
    "3121:311590": {
        "document": {
            "id": "3121:311590",
            "name": "Field",
            "type": "INSTANCE",
            "scrollBehavior": "SCROLLS",
            "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "I3121:311590;518:154896",
                    "name": "Header",
                    "type": "FRAME",
                    "scrollBehavior": "SCROLLS",
                    "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
```

.... [6000 lines of nested json]